# MySQL Query Efficiency w/ Multiple CTEs, Joins, etc

Tags: mysql

How can this query be re-written to be faster/more efficient?

---

```sql
EXPLAIN
WITH t_temp AS
    (
        SELECT
            id AS ID,
            dt AS DT,
            yrwk YRWK,
            `open` AS O,
            `close` AS C,
            piv3 AS S
        FROM
            t_1min_signals
        WHERE piv3 IN
            (1,3)
    ),

cte AS 
    (
        SELECT
              (
                    SELECT id
                    FROM t_temp AS cls
                    WHERE cls.yrwk = opn.yrwk
                        AND cls.dt > opn.dt
# --- LONG -----------------------------------------                        
                        AND cls.s = 1 AND opn.s = 3
# --- SHORT ----------------------------------------                            
#                       AND cls.s = 3 AND opn.s = 1
# --------------------------------------------------
                    ORDER BY cls.dt
                    LIMIT 1
                ) c_id,
                opn.id AS o_id
        FROM t_temp AS opn
    )
    
SELECT
    cte.o_id O_ID,
    opv.dt O_DATE,
    opv.o `OPEN`,
    cte.c_id C_ID,
    clv.dt C_DATE,
    clv.c `CLOSE`,
# --- LONG ------------------------------
    (clv.c - opv.o) `LONG P/L`
# --- SHORT -----------------------------
#   (opv.o - clv.c) `SHORT P/L`

FROM cte
INNER JOIN t_temp AS clv
    ON cte.c_id = clv.id
INNER JOIN t_temp AS opv
    ON cte.o_id = opv.id
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | \N | ALL | \N | \N | \N | \N | 1845328 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | t_1min_signals | \N | eq_ref | PRIMARY,piv3,id_yrwk_piv3,id_dt_yrwk_open_close_piv3 | PRIMARY | 8 | cte.c_id | 1 | 36.40 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | t_1min_signals | \N | eq_ref | PRIMARY,piv3,id_yrwk_piv3,id_dt_yrwk_open_close_piv3 | PRIMARY | 8 | cte.o_id | 1 | 36.40 | Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | t_1min_signals | \N | index | piv3 | dt_yrwk_piv3 | 9 | \N | 5068912 | 36.40 | Using where; Using index |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t_1min_signals | \N | index | dt,yrwk,piv3,yrwk_piv3,dt_yrwk_piv3,id_dt_yrwk_open_close_piv3 | dt | 5 | \N | 2077 | 0.61 | Using where |

Running MySQL 8.0.23, Dedicated Win10, 128GB fast ram, separate SSDs for OS/Data (fastest SSDs out there right now), i5.

5.2mil rows, InnoDB, the Piv3 column is TINYINT, unsigned (only values of 0, 1 or 3).
This query is running 15+hrs.

**UPDATE 1** - had a copy/paste issue- the original code is corrected now without the repeated line. Also included the EXPLAIN. I switch between the `LONG` and `SHORT` Arguments to run each individually, but ultimately, if it's faster/easier I'd prefer them to run them together w/ results in the same table. Not sure if that's possible or not.

**UPDATE 2** - Things I have tried:

- created temp table for the source table- but- temp tables only allow
  you to query against them once, and the criteria in my query requires
  them to hit    the table multiple times. This produces the 'cannot
  reopen table'    errors.
- created a view for the source table, with the same results as the temp table. I get the error of 'cannot reopen table'
- tried the bulk of the source table (id, dt, yrwk, open, close- these are used over and over in tons of queries, and the Piv3 variable
  is switched out with other columns to get the results later) as a
  view and again a temp table, and joined the Piv3 column- same results
  as above.
- additionally, for some reason whenever I use a view, I get errornum 28 (not enough space on device). Which, I have hundreds of gigs of
  available space on all drives available, and made sure the tmpdir is
  pointed to that free space- still get the error.

**UPDATE 3 - EXPLAIN w/ JSON**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "2587034.34"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "cte",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1845328,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 1845328,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "23069.10",
            "eval_cost": "184532.80",
            "prefix_cost": "207601.90",
            "data_read_per_join": "42M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "c_id",
            "o_id"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`cte`.`c_id` is not null)",
          "materialized_from_subquery": {
            "using_temporary_table": true,
            "dependent": false,
            "cacheable": true,
            "query_block": {
              "select_id": 2,
              "cost_info": {
                "query_cost": "626557.92"
              },
              "table": {
                "table_name": "t_1min_signals",
                "access_type": "index",
                "possible_keys": [
                  "piv3"
                ],
                "key": "dt_yrwk_piv3",
                "used_key_parts": [
                  "dt",
                  "yrwk",
                  "piv3"
                ],
                "key_length": "9",
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 5068912,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 1845328,
                "filtered": "36.40",
                "using_index": true,
                "cost_info": {
                  "read_cost": "442025.12",
                  "eval_cost": "184532.81",
                  "prefix_cost": "626557.92",
                  "data_read_per_join": "605M"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                  "id",
                  "dt",
                  "yrwk",
                  "piv3"
                ],
                "attached_condition": "(`badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`piv3` in (1,3))"
              },
              "select_list_subqueries": [
                {
                  "dependent": true,
                  "cacheable": false,
                  "query_block": {
                    "select_id": 3,
                    "cost_info": {
                      "query_cost": "2305.89"
                    },
                    "ordering_operation": {
                      "using_filesort": false,
                      "table": {
                        "table_name": "t_1min_signals",
                        "access_type": "index",
                        "possible_keys": [
                          "dt",
                          "yrwk",
                          "piv3",
                          "yrwk_piv3",
                          "dt_yrwk_piv3",
                          "id_dt_yrwk_open_close_piv3"
                        ],
                        "key": "dt",
                        "used_key_parts": [
                          "dt"
                        ],
                        "key_length": "5",
                        "rows_examined_per_scan": 2077,
                        "rows_produced_per_join": 813,
                        "filtered": "0.61",
                        "cost_info": {
                          "read_cost": "2061.96",
                          "eval_cost": "81.30",
                          "prefix_cost": "2305.89",
                          "data_read_per_join": "273K"
                        },
                        "used_columns": [
                          "id",
                          "dt",
                          "yrwk",
                          "piv3"
                        ],
                        "attached_condition": "((`badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`piv3` = 1) and (`badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`yrwk` = `badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`yrwk`) and (`badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`dt` > `badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`dt`) and (`badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`piv3` = 3))"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "t_1min_signals",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY",
            "piv3",
            "id_yrwk_piv3",
            "id_dt_yrwk_open_close_piv3"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "8",
          "ref": [
            "cte.c_id"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 671788,
          "filtered": "36.40",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "1559857.56",
            "eval_cost": "67178.83",
            "prefix_cost": "1951992.26",
            "data_read_per_join": "220M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "dt",
            "close",
            "piv3"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`piv3` in (1,3))"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "t_1min_signals",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY",
            "piv3",
            "id_yrwk_piv3",
            "id_dt_yrwk_open_close_piv3"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "8",
          "ref": [
            "cte.o_id"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 244563,
          "filtered": "36.40",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "567863.26",
            "eval_cost": "24456.33",
            "prefix_cost": "2587034.34",
            "data_read_per_join": "80M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "dt",
            "open",
            "piv3"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`badassery`.`t_1min_signals`.`piv3` in (1,3))"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 4 - EXPLAIN TREE**

```
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1088836.90 rows=244563)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=853645.81 rows=671788)
        -> Filter: (cte.c_id is not null)  (cost=207601.90 rows=1845328)
            -> Table scan on cte  (cost=207601.90 rows=1845328)
                -> Materialize CTE cte  (cost=542296.69 rows=1845328)
                    -> Filter: (t_1min_signals.piv3 in (1,3))  (cost=542296.69 rows=1845328)
                        -> Index scan on t_1min_signals using id_dt_yrwk_open_close_piv3  (cost=542296.69 rows=5068912)
                    -> Select #3 (subquery in projection; dependent)
                        -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=20.04 rows=1)
                            -> Filter: ((t_1min_signals.piv3 = 1) and (t_1min_signals.yrwk = t_1min_signals.yrwk) and (t_1min_signals.dt > t_1min_signals.dt) and (t_1min_signals.piv3 = 3))  (cost=20.04 rows=5)
                                -> Index scan on t_1min_signals using dt  (cost=20.04 rows=801)
        -> Filter: (t_1min_signals.piv3 in (1,3))  (cost=0.25 rows=0)
            -> Single-row index lookup on t_1min_signals using PRIMARY (id=cte.c_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
    -> Filter: (t_1min_signals.piv3 in (1,3))  (cost=0.25 rows=0)
        -> Single-row index lookup on t_1min_signals using PRIMARY (id=cte.o_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
```

Comment: You're going to have to learn to use `EXPLAIN` here.  The first thing to consider optimizing, maybe via indices, is the SQL code itself.  Next thing to check is the impact of the CTEs.  AFAIK MySQL may or may not materialize the CTEs, depending on your query.  Try a few variations and find the best option.

Comment: This is impossible:  `AND  cls.s = 1  AND  cls.s = 3`  Do you need an `OR` somewhere?

Comment: What you can do is replace CTEs with temporary tables and create indexes over these temp tables. In my tests, this is faster than CTEs in big tables.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I updated the original post to correct the code, add the EXPLAIN, and some updated notes of things I have tried/failed, and more details of my setup.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the EXPLAIN output. Honestly, not entirely sure how to use it/interpret it. I sense that using/setting up the correct keys/indexes will solve everything. Is it better to set up one index for each individual column? Or group all the columns used into one index? Or, combinations of columns into an index based on what the query needs? All the above? Or is it WORSE to do all the above? Thank you for your insights!

Comment: @RickJames haha yes. I had a copy/paste issue there. Basically, there's 2 scenarios in this query (LONG and SHORT)- and I need the output for both. I don't know how to combine them into one query, and have it still be efficient, so I was commenting out each line and running each scenario individually. Perhaps there's a more efficient way to do this? I'd love to hear your input.

Comment: @FrancoMorero Read the update 2 I added and the problems I had with creating Temp Tables. Any ideas/suggestions? thank you

Comment: @Strawberry I updated the original post to add EXPLAIN output, and a lot more details. Any suggestions on how to improve this query?

Comment: Update 3 Added- Explain w/ JSON

Comment: Update 4 - Added Explain Tree. You can see where the big bulk of the cost is, I just don't know how to do it better? Thank you for any insights you can give!

Answer (score 0):

```
( SELECT ... SHORT ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... LONG ... )
```

That combined query is twice as long, but does everything in a single query, producing a single resultset.

Change `ALL` to `DISTINCT` if there are duplicates and you wish them to be removed.

Stick an `ORDER BY` at the very end if you want the result sorted.

If the `piv3` being 1 or 3 is the same as the 1 and 3 for `s` some simplification may be desirable?

I think that the innermost `SELECT` cannot see `opn`.  That is, the query looks invalid.

The "composite" `INDEX(yrwk, s, dt)`, may help.  (`dt` needs to be third.)

Comment: Can you explain why the dt needs to be 3rd in the composite? I didn't realize the order made a difference in the keys... thank you!

Comment: @user3718843 - Think about a list of people that is sorted by lastname, but what you have is only the first name.  Put `=` columns first in an index.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Great blog post- thank you it helped me understand.

Comment: Why do you think that the inner select can't see opn, or the query is invalid? I don't see it... Thank you!